# how to export data frame (R) into Oracle table

Tags: r, oracle, csv

I need a piece of advice how to transfer data from R into Oracle table.

I have a R-dataframe and I would like to transfer it into the specific Oracle table (the whole dataframe or some columns).

As an option, transfer dataframe which is placed in a csv file via R into Oracle.

I have scanned similar items throughout the inet but not find a clear and plain examples.

Comment: Are you using `ROracle`? If yes you can use `dbWriteTable`

Comment: @Batanichek
thanks for help. I will try your option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the method `dbWriteTable` of the package [RJDBC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/index.html)

Here an example

```
 dbWriteTable(jdbcConnection,"TABLE_NAME",data.frame.name.,   rownames=FALSE, overwrite = TRUE, append = FALSE)
```

Adjust options as required. For overwrite TRUE a new table is created in the schema of your connection user.

Comment: thanks for the help. I will use it soon.

any other options besides RJDBC? This package seems to be very slow considering the large dataframe transfer? mybe RORacle?

Comment: As commented above you may use the same function with ROracle. But  have no experiance with it. For very large data set in `csv` format  I'd prefer direct import in DB (e.g. extranal table or SQL*loader) and than read in `R`...

Comment: thanks for your comment. I will take it into my consideration.