# How to export R table to Oracle database

Tags: oracle, rstudio

I'm trying to export a R dataframe to Oracle database. 
I read this post: [how to export data frame (R) into Oracle table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365741/how-to-export-data-frame-r-into-oracle-table). In short,

```
dbWriteTable(jdbcConnection,"TABLE_NAME",data.frame.name.,   rownames=FALSE, overwrite = TRUE, append = FALSE)
```

However, I do not know what is 'jdbcConnection' and how to declare it.

BTW I'm able to connect Oracle with R Studio using RODBC package.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer in that link cites the [`RJDBC` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/index.html), which connects to the SQL database using the Java JDBC driver, in this case, the driver for Oracle.  If you poke around the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/RJDBC.pdf), you will find some boilerplate code for how to do this:

```
drv <- JDBC("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", "/path/to/ojdbc6.jar", " ")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orclt")
dbWriteTable(conn, "TABLE_NAME", data.frame.name, rownames=FALSE, overwrite = TRUE, append = FALSE)
```

Note that to make the above work, you will need locally the `ojdbc6.jar` JAR file for the Oracle JDBC driver.  You may download this from the Oracle site directly if you don't already have it.  The second parameter being used above in the call to `dbConnect` is the JDBC url for your Oracle instance.  Refer to any number of posts on Stack Overflow to learn how to form the appropriate URL for your Oracle instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example [based on this doc](https://www.r-bloggers.com/connecting-r-to-an-oracle-database-with-rjdbc/):

```
# Load RJDBC library
library(RJDBC)

# Create connection driver and open connection
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", classPath="lib/ojdbc6.jar")
jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//database.hostname.com:port/service_name_or_sid", "username", "password")

# Write to table
dbWriteTable(jdbcConnection,"TABLE_NAME",data.frame.name, rownames=FALSE, overwrite = TRUE, append = FALSE)
```