# How to upload data into Oracle db from R?

Tags: r, oracle, jdbc

I need to upload data from R into Oracle database.
I follow to the recommendations from this question
[how to export data frame (R) into Oracle table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365741/how-to-export-data-frame-r-into-oracle-table).

I use the code:

```
dbWriteTable(con_dwh, "table_db", table_in_R, 
         append =T, row.names=F, overwrite = F)
```

where `con_dwh` is a JDBC conection to Oracle database.

Hovewer I've got the error message:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate (NaN)
```

I am a little bit confused on the error occured.

Could someone help me?

Comment: It might be that one of the rows has a value that is not interpreted correctly. Try inserting one row. If it works, add 10 or 50 rows (depending on how much you have). Keep going until you hit the failure again, then try to identify which row of the new batch is the culprit. If finding the row doesn't make it abundantly clear which value is at fault, come back and [edit] your question to include at least one good row and one bad row. Good luck!

Comment: @r2evans  I've tried to insert 1 row. Result - error ORA-00947. I have no idea why this error occurs. Could this be due to the identity column values of which myst be generated automatically when inserting data?

Comment: I don't work with Oracle, so I can really only help advise the process to determine the problem. Perhaps in addition to the "individual rows" thing I suggested, you also try single or small sets of columns until you can insert without error, and then keep working up to resolve which column is doing it. (BTW: [ORA-00947](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00947.php) suggests empty values, either `""` or `NA`, might be an issue. I also don't use `JDBC`, preferring the non-java `odbc`, so perhaps that is also at play here.

Comment: `ORA-00947` simple means that the table has more columns that the data frame. Simple use `overwrite = T, append = F` and it disappears...

Comment: @MarmiteBomber indeed the problem disappeared. But I faced another problem that R couldn't insert rows with `na`. How to hadle it?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber the problem arose due to in the Oracle db table  containts identity column. And when inserting data from R it is not nessecary to specify it because the value generates automatically. When I user `overwrite=T, append =F` ithe identity column disappear. And this is not the proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reasons in `dbWriteTable` a  `NA` value in a `num` columns fails to be inserted as  `NULL`, which works fine for `chr` column.

So the workaround is to replace the  `NA` in the `num` column with a valid number - i#m using `0``.

If you need to end with `null`in the table use some *special* number and  `UPDATE` to null in the database.

```
> df <- data.frame(col1 = c('x',NA,'y'), col2 = c(1,NA,NA))
> 
> df
  col1 col2
1    x    1
2 <NA>   NA
3    y   NA
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ col1: chr  "x" NA "y"
 $ col2: num  1 NA NA
> 
> dbWriteTable(jdbcConnection,"TEST", df,   rownames=FALSE, overwrite = TRUE, append = FALSE)  
Fehler in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate (NaN)
> 
> df[is.na(df$col2),"col2"] <- 0
> df
  col1 col2
1    x    1
2 <NA>    0
3    y    0
> 
> dbWriteTable(jdbcConnection,"TEST", df,   rownames=FALSE, overwrite = TRUE, append = FALSE) 
>
```

In the DB

```
select * from test

COL1           COL2
-------- ----------
x                 1
                  0
y                 0
```

For *integer* data  type `int` the insert of `NA` *works* but the inserted value is `-2147483648` which is also not good.

```
df <- data.frame(  id  = c(as.integer(NA),as.integer(NA)) )
dbWriteTable(jdbcConnection,"TEST", df,   rownames=FALSE, overwrite = TRUE, append = FALSE) 

## OK but

select * from test

ID
-2147483648
-2147483648
```

This has probably to do with the internal storage of NA as integer.

Note produced with `R version 4.0.4`  and `RJDBC_0.2-8`.