# How to append data from R to Oracle db table with identity column

Tags: r, oracle

I created a table in Oracle like

```
Create table t1 
(id_record  NUMERIC GENERATED AS IDENTITY START WITH 500000 NOT NULL,
col1 numeric(2,0),
col2 varchar(10),
primary key(id_record))
```

where  `id_record` is identity column the value of which is generated automatically when appending data to table.

I create a data.frame in R with 2 columns (`table_in_R <- data.frame(col1, col2)`). Let's skip the values of data frame for simplicity reasons.

When I append data from R to Oracle db using the following code

```
dbWriteTable(con, 't1', table_in_R, 
         append =T, row.names=F, overwrite = F)
```

where `con` is a connection object the error `ORA-00947` arises and no data appended.

When I slightly modify my code (`append = F`, `overwrite = T`).

```
dbWriteTable(con_dwh, 't1', table_in_R, 
         append =FALSE, row.names=F, overwrite = TRUE)
```

the data is appended, but the identity column `id_record` is dropped.

How can I append data to Oracle db without dropping the identity column?

Comment: I added an *workaround* that may work with the `default on null identity` - use at your own risk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd **never** (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70712578/4808122) answer) recommend this one step approach where the `dbWriteTable`directly maintains the target table.

Instead I'd *recommend* a two step approach, where the `R` part fills a *temporary* table (with `overwrite = T` i.e. `DROP` and `CREATE`)

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(as.integer(1),as.integer(0)), col2 = c('x',NA))
dbWriteTable(jdbcConnection,"TEMP", df,   rownames=FALSE, overwrite = TRUE, append = FALSE)
```

In the *second step* you simple *adds* the new rows to the target table using

`insert into t1(col1,col2) select col1,col2 from temp;`

You may call it direct with a database connection or also from `R`:

```
res <-   dbSendUpdate(jdbcConnection,"insert into t1(col1,col2) select col1,col2 from temp")
```

Note there *is* a workaround anyway:

1. Define the *identity column* as

   `id_record  NUMERIC GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY`

This configuration of the *identity column*  provides  the correct sequence value instead of the `NULL` value - but you will *fail* on the above linked problem of *Inserting `NULL` in a Number column*.

2. So the second trick is to use a *character* `NA` in the data.frame

Add the
identity column to your data.frame and fill it with all `as.character(NA)`.

```
df <- data.frame(id_record =c(as.character(NA),as.character(NA) ), col1 = c(as.integer(1),as.integer(0)), col2 = c('x',NA))
dbWriteTable(jdbcConnection,"T1", df,   rownames=FALSE, overwrite = F, append = T)
```

Test works fine, but as mentioned I'd recommend the two step approach.

Comment: I experience the issue with `overwrite = T` on the 1 step because it changes the types of variables in the temp table. For example the date column is changed by varchar variable. This is the big source of problem when I append data to the target table on the 2 step.

Comment: Yes, this is exact the reason I'd prefer the two step appproach with a `temp` table. Let  `dbWriteTable` with *best effort* to insert the data and than *explicitely* fix the  problems. Do not let `dbWiteTable` make *implicit* conversions.
Use  `to_date` to repair the  `DATE` columns, fix the numeric  `NULLS` etc. BTW you'll *have to* use `overwrite = F` if your `VARCHAR2` columns are longer than 255, otherwise you'll get 
`ORA-12899: value too large for column ... maximum: 255)`.  Good luck!   @Davit

Comment: `to_date` for example doesn't work in my case. I've already trid this version too. Unfortunately didn't succed.

Comment: Caution SO doesn't like *doesn't work*;) Whats wrong with `to_date(col,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')`? @Davit

Comment: The problem is when I run this code `to_date(col,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')` the variable I get is varchar, not date as I would like.

Comment: pls open an other question and demonstrate @Davit  `select to_date('2021-01-18 13:30:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual` returns a `DATE` value

Comment: maybe due to `2021-01-18 13:30:00` is date format initially. In my case `col` is varchar format